# Are there other way to say Eclipse and project that my configuration file reside in that folder?

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration, classpath

I have a configuration file in the conf folder in my project hierarchy. Instead just putting file under src folder, are there other way to say Eclipse and project that my configuration file reside in that folder?

I see a .classpath file in the same hierarchy of project. I donot remember whether it is created by Git or Eclipse. If it is created with Eclipse, is it possible to append some new information to it namely saying configuration file is in conf folder?

project hierarchy;

```
project
   | - - src
   | - - ...
   | - - conf
           | - - logback
                    | - - logback.xml
```

Don't give logback **specific** answer, I just used that name to make question more meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

.classpath is created by Eclipse.
you should add a new item to .classpath file as source folder to make Eclipse include/compile contents of it and output to bin(output) folder.
i.e.

<classpathentry kind="src" path="conf"/>

this way you can see your configuration/whatever files in exported jar file after export a jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the conf folder in package explorer, Build Path/Use as a source folder

Answer (score 0):

if im not mistaken, the classpath file is created by eclipse. [see this](http://eclim.org/vim/java/classpath.html)

In the build path settings of your project, you can add a source directory, in your example it's the logback dir then specify the output folder (ie target/classes in a java project)